# How to block custom url pattern using nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

Im trying to block read of web.xml from the URL pattern in nginx for this i tried this it doesn't work for me

```
location ~* \web.xml$ {
return 404;
 }
```

This is the URL pattern which contain **web.xml**

```
https://example.com/group/model?p_p_id=MYWAR_INSTANCE&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=%2FWEBINF%2Fweb.xml&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelage&p_p_col_id=column2&p_p_col_count=1&repaintAll=1&sh=900&sw=1440&cw=1425&ch=246&vw=1144&vh=1&fr=
```

This Work for me

```
if ($args ~* "/?web.xml") {
        rewrite ^ /group/guest last;
    }
```

Comment: No question mark (`?`) in the url? Really?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
location ^~ /web.xml {
return 404;
 }
```

Comment: Same issue it returns the Web.xml not 404

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp location:

```
location ~* ^(.*)web.xml(.*)$ {
    return 404;    
}
```